# If $\exists k>1$ odd such that $E(X-E(X))^k=0$, then is X symmetric?

Tags: probability

If $\exists k>1$ odd such that $E(X-E(X))^k=0$, then is X symmetric?

I know that the converse is true, in fact, if X is symmetric, then all odd moments will be zero.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you're right. I forgot to add the condition k>1... I've edited the question now.

Comment: You mean $E[(X-E[X])^k]$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes

Comment: What is a symmetric random variable?  Is it a random variable such that $X-a$ and $a-X$ are identically distributed for some $a$?

Comment: I believe that even  if the condition holds for all odd integers $k$ the distribution may not be symmetric, but constructing such a distribution appears to be very difficult.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for you comment and answer. ;)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941786/example-of-a-distribution-that-is-not-symmetric-but-has-a-skewness-of-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a real-valued random variable $X$ that is not symmetric (I am guessing that it means $X-a$ and $a-X$ are identically distributed for some constant $a$) and, for a given odd integer $k>1$, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\big(X-\mathbb{E}[X]\big)^k\right]=0\,.$$
Fix an odd integer $k>1$.  Take for example a random variable $X$ with three possible values $-2$, $1$, and $3$ such that $$\mathbb{P}[X=-2]=\frac{3^k-3}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}-5}\,,$$ $$\mathbb{P}[X=1]=\frac{2\cdot 3^k-3\cdot2^k}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}-5}\,,$$ and $$\mathbb{P}[X=3]=\frac{2^k-2}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}-5}\,.$$
Then,
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=0\text{ and }\mathbb{E}\left[X^k\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\big(X-\mathbb{E}[X]\big)^k\right]=0\,.$$
Nonetheless, I think this should be true: if $X$ is an integrable real-valued random variable and $\mathbb{E}\left[\big(X-\mathbb{E}[X]\big)^k\right]=0$ for every odd integer $k>1$, then $X$ is symmetric about $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

---

My claim in the paragraph above indeed holds.  Without loss of generality, suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$.  Let $\varphi_X$ denote the characteristic function of $X$, namely, $\varphi_X(t)=\mathbb{E}\big[\exp(\text{i}tX)\big]$ for all real numbers $t$.  Thus,
$$\varphi_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\exp(\text{i}tx)\,\text{d}P_X(x)\,,$$
where $P_X$ is the probability measure of $X$.  Observe that $\varphi_X$ is an even function.  Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\chi_E$ denotes the indicator function of $E$.  Then, we see that
$$P_X(E)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\exp(-\text{i}ts)\,\varphi_X(t)\,\chi_E(s)\,\text{d}s\,\text{d}t\,.$$
Since $\varphi_X$ is even, it follows that $$P_X(-E)=P_X(+E)$$ for any measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$.  Consequently, $X$ is symmetric about $0$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. ;)

Comment: This comment serves as a future reference to myself:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941786/example-of-a-distribution-that-is-not-symmetric-but-has-a-skewness-of-zero

Answer (score 2):

Compute the first 3 moments of Poisson ($\lambda$) distribution explicitly. You will find that there is a value of $\lambda$ for which $E(X-EX)^{3}=0$. Obviously Poisson distribition is not symmetric about any point. [ $EX=\lambda,EX^{2}=\lambda^{2}+\lambda,EX^{3}=\lambda^{3}+3\lambda^{2}+\lambda$, so $E(X-EX)^{3}=\lambda (3\lambda+1-3\lambda^{2})$ which is $0$ when $\lambda =\frac {\sqrt 7+\sqrt 3} {2\sqrt 3}$.

Comment: Kavi, I thought I understood your answer, but the skewness of the Poisson is $1/\sqrt{\lambda}$. Also, the only value I could think of would be when $\lambda=0$ but this value cannot be, since it creates problems on how to define the poisson...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. My calculation shows that $E(X-EX)^{3}=\lambda+3\lambda^{2}-2\lambda^{3}$ and there is a positive solution to this equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

From the two links above, I think it should be $E(X-E(X))^3=E(X^3)-3\lambda^3-\lambda^3=\lambda$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I have computed $E(X-EX)^{3}$ three times and I don't think the value is $\lambda$. I still believe my answer is correct.

Comment: Kavi, Did you check the Wikipedia links? Unless you show the calculations I don't know how you get what you get... I've also used Mathematica -  with the CentralMoment or the Moment commands - and I get $\lambda$, and only then does it make sense the value for skewness in wikipedia.