# Why is the Poisson distribution not necessarily symmetrical even though it has constant variance?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, variance, poisson-distribution

The variance of $X \sim$Poisson$(\lambda)$ is $\lambda$, which is a constant. Intuitively, I take this to be that the values of $X$ are symmetrically distributed; however, many Poisson distributions I have seen are wildly skewed to one side. So how can I reconcile these 2 things? Why is the Poisson distribution not necessarily symmetrical even though it has constant variance?

Comment: Why do you see variance as an indication of symmetry (and also, what does it mean to be "constant" here, as there is no variable parameter -- constant as opposed to what?)

Comment: The Poisson distribution has a semi-infinite support on non-negative integers so, looking from the median, it has a finite tail to the left and an infinite tail to the right and thus is not symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the variance of a distribution is always a function of the parameters of that distribution. If you take the parameters ($\lambda$ in this case) as constants, then the variance is also always a constant.

This has nothing to do with symmetry of the distribution, whioch is better expressed by the Skewness of the distribution.

Comment: And even then you can have asymmetric distributions with zero skewness such as the examples at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1942908/6460